# Is Default Websphere Portal 8.0.0 Default Theme Responsive?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, themes, websphere-portal

I have been hopping from one IBM article to another in search of exploring the responsive features of WebSphere portal 8 default theme. IBM says it is responsive by default. I tried accessing a portal page , both a different view-port as well as from an Android application(using IBM Worklight) but nothing was responsive. So : Is the default WebSphere portal theme responsive ? If no, how do I enable the responsiveness? I am not looking to code media queries etc , just want to explore OOB responsive features of IBM Websphere Portal 8 default. 
There are lot of articles that point to IBM Web Experience Factory or IBM Mobile Portal Accelerator. Those are different products and I am not interested in them. And I believe they are not mandatory to explore responsiveness in a Portal application. 
Appreciate !!!
Kapil S Raina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you need to install fixpack at least 8.0.0.1 to get responsive theme. There was no responsive theme in 8.0.0.0. See [Whats new in 8.0.0.1](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Readme%208.0.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=WebSphere_Portal_and_Web_Content_Manager_V8.0.0.1_Readme_8001&content=pdcontent). It also contains some important updates to WCM and CTC if you are using these. Remember to enable new features after installing fixpack.

Comment: Yup, it is 8.0.0.1 . Thanks.